# Getting Balance Value in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

How to calculate the balance in SSRS?
Can we achieve in Presentation Layer instead of Database Layer? 
Currently I am using Tablix, Am I supposed to use Matrix instead?
Is there a way to calculate that in Tablix?
The first picture is just to show the logic I need.

[image]

It gives no error but the calculation is not what I need.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a matrix set up like:
[image]

There are 3 groups here:

1. Row Group: group by month
2. "In" column group: group by TotalPt, filter to >= 0
3. "Out" column group: group by TotalPt, filter to < 0

Each of the number fields can contain the same expression `sum(Fields!TotalPt.Value)` as the grouping will handle the rest.

Comment: I didn't group by for that. I have made it calculated inside the dataset query. I tried using ReportItems but I am get an error.

Comment: @4stars Can you show your calculation in the dataset query, and the error ReportItems gives you please?

Comment: @4stars Which part gives you the withdrawal?

Comment: I didn't have separate column for this, It it is negative, I take it as Withdrawal

Comment: The result balance of each month will be carried to consecutive month. For example ,u have balance -1(for January), then the balance for February will be (-1+6+0)=5, and so on.

Comment: You can use RunningValue() then. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255229.aspx